# How to create MySQL field letter autoincrement rule in Java

Tags: java, mysql

Now I have a business problem. There is a field in MySQL database that needs letters to be added automatically. For example, AA, AB, AC, AD and AAA, AAB, AAC, ABC and AAAA, AAAB, AAAC

The project uses springboot, the database is mysql, and the table category has a field code that needs to grow by itself. How to achieve it

This is an alphabetical rule I wrote, an entity class I created, and I don't know if it fits into the business scenario

```
public static String createNext(String string) {
       char[]tempChar=string.toCharArray();
        for (int i=tempChar.length-1;i>=1;i--){
            if (tempChar[i]<'Z'){
                tempChar[i]=(char)(tempChar[i]+1);
                break;
            }else {
                tempChar[i]='A';
                tempChar[i-1]=(char)(tempChar[i-1]+1);
                if (tempChar[i-1]<='Z'){
                    i=0;
                }
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(tempChar);
    }
```

Comment: This is a tricky thing to do, even in Java, which is not the same as doing it in your MySQL database.  For MySQL, I would suggest just generating the letter sequence when you query.